# django - template tag problem using AuthenticationForm

Tags: django, forms, authentication, django-templates

I am trying to put a login form in every page in my web that uses django.contrib.auth.views.login. I created a templatetag in templatetags/mytags.py, where I define a function called get_login wich looks like this:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('registration/login.html', takes_context=True)
def get_login(context):
    ...
    return {'formLogin':  mark_safe(AuthenticationForm())}
```

...and in base.html:

```
{% load mytags  %}{% get_login  %}
```

The problem now is that the template (registration/login.html) doesnt recognize `{{ formLogin.username }}`,`{{ formLogin.password }}`... and so on.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mark_safe` returns an instance of `django.utils.safestring.SafeString`, not a form, so those lookups will fail. I don't think there's anything wrong with directly returning the form (that's what all the generic views in `django.contrib.auth` do when populating templates, for instance). Just change your return statement to

```
return {'formLogin': AuthenticationForm()}
```

and it should work.